# Tensorflow tf.Variable not able to perform addition

Tags: tensorflow

I am able to perform addition using constant but not able to perform through tf.Variable

Below code is working fine when I am using constant for addition.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(5)
b = tf.constant(6)

sess = tf.Session()
result = sess.run(a + b)
print(result)
```

But when I tried with tf.Variable it is not working, Here is mine code

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(5)
b = tf.Variable(6)

sess = tf.Session()
result = sess.run(a + b)
print(result)
```

Can somebody help me ? Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the variables firstly:

```
import tensorflow as tf
​
a = tf.Variable(5)
b = tf.Variable(6)
​    ​
sess = tf.Session()
```

Initialize variables:

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())     

result = sess.run(a + b)

print(result)
11
```

---

You can read more about variable initialization [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables#initializing_variables), which says ***Unlike tf.Tensor objects, a tf.Variable exists outside the context of a single session.run call***. So ***Before you can use a variable, it must be initialized***. The initialization is Session specific, which means whenever you start a new session, and want to use these variables, you'll have to initialize them firstly.

Comment: thanks, but can you tell me what this line will do sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()). It would be great if you explain it briefly. Thanks !!!

Comment: You can read [initializing variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables#initializing_variables) here, which says *Unlike tf.Tensor objects, a tf.Variable exists outside the context of a single session.run call.* So ***Before you can use a variable, it must be initialized.***.  The initialization is Session specific, which means whenever you start a new session, and want to use these variables, you'll have to initialize them firstly.